# Having trouble filtering out duplicate paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm having a bit of a problem removing duplicate paths from a return in Neo4j.

Here is the cypher query:

```
MATCH (subA:`Subaccount` {acct: 199345})-[:`contains`]->(intA:`Physical Interface`)-[conn:`connects`]-(intB:`Physical Interface`)<-[:`contains`]-(subB:`Subaccount`)
RETURN DISTINCT id(conn), subA.name, intA.name, intB.name AS `Connected Host Interface`, subB.name AS `Connected Host`, subB.acct AS `Connected Host Account`
ORDER BY id(conn);
```

This returns the following result set:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id(conn) | subA.name           | intA.name     | Connected Host Interface | Connected Host               | Connected Host Account |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 30832    | "fw.rrfaae.com"     | "ethernet0/0" | "Gi0/1"                  | "b3s5r12k11s1.liquidweb.com" | 22                     |
| 30833    | "fw.rrfaae.com"     | "ethernet0/1" | "Gi0/48"                 | "sw.rrfaae.com"              | 199345                 |
| 30833    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/48"      | "ethernet0/1"            | "fw.rrfaae.com"              | 199345                 |
| 30834    | "dummy2.rrfaae.com" | "eth0"        | "Gi0/2"                  | "b3s5r12k11s1.liquidweb.com" | 22                     |
| 30835    | "dummy1.rrfaae.com" | "eth0"        | "Gi0/3"                  | "b3s5r12k11s1.liquidweb.com" | 22                     |
| 30836    | "dummy1.rrfaae.com" | "eth1"        | "eth1"                   | "dummy2.rrfaae.com"          | 199345                 |
| 30836    | "dummy2.rrfaae.com" | "eth1"        | "eth1"                   | "dummy1.rrfaae.com"          | 199345                 |
| 30837    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/1"       | "eth0"                   | "web01.rrfaae.com"           | 199345                 |
| 30837    | "web01.rrfaae.com"  | "eth0"        | "Gi0/1"                  | "sw.rrfaae.com"              | 199345                 |
| 30838    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/2"       | "eth1"                   | "web01.rrfaae.com"           | 199345                 |
| 30838    | "web01.rrfaae.com"  | "eth1"        | "Gi0/2"                  | "sw.rrfaae.com"              | 199345                 |
| 30840    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/4"       | "eth1"                   | "web02.rrfaae.com"           | 199345                 |
| 30840    | "web02.rrfaae.com"  | "eth1"        | "Gi0/4"                  | "sw.rrfaae.com"              | 199345                 |
| 30841    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/3"       | "eth0"                   | "web02.rrfaae.com"           | 199345                 |
| 30841    | "web02.rrfaae.com"  | "eth0"        | "Gi0/3"                  | "sw.rrfaae.com"              | 199345                 |
| 30842    | "db01.rrfaae.com"   | "serial"      | "serial"                 | "db02.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30842    | "db02.rrfaae.com"   | "serial"      | "serial"                 | "db01.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30843    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/5"       | "eth0"                   | "db01.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30843    | "db01.rrfaae.com"   | "eth0"        | "Gi0/5"                  | "sw.rrfaae.com"              | 199345                 |
| 30844    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/6"       | "eth1"                   | "db01.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30844    | "db01.rrfaae.com"   | "eth1"        | "Gi0/6"                  | "sw.rrfaae.com"              | 199345                 |
| 30845    | "db02.rrfaae.com"   | "eth2"        | "eth2"                   | "db01.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30845    | "db01.rrfaae.com"   | "eth2"        | "eth2"                   | "db02.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30846    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/7"       | "eth0"                   | "db02.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30846    | "db02.rrfaae.com"   | "eth0"        | "Gi0/7"                  | "sw.rrfaae.com"              | 199345                 |
| 30847    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/8"       | "eth1"                   | "db02.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30847    | "db02.rrfaae.com"   | "eth1"        | "Gi0/8"                  | "sw.rrfaae.com"              | 199345                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The one possible solution I was [looking at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410127/cypher-return-twice-for-nodes-that-connected-in-bi-directional-relationship/14410552) recommend using a `WHERE id(a) < id(b)` type clause.

If subA wasn't being matched based on a property, this would work. However, since it is, some results that should return wouldn't:

Query:

```
MATCH (subA:`Subaccount` {acct: 199345})-[:`contains`]->(intA:`Physical Interface`)-[conn:`connects`]-(intB:`Physical Interface`)<-[:`contains`]-(subB:`Subaccount`)
WHERE id(subA) < id(subB)
RETURN DISTINCT id(conn), subA.name, intA.name, intB.name AS `Connected Host Interface`, subB.name AS `Connected Host`, subB.acct AS `Connected Host Account`
ORDER BY id(conn);
```

Result set:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id(conn) | subA.name           | intA.name     | Connected Host Interface | Connected Host      | Connected Host Account |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 30833    | "fw.rrfaae.com"     | "ethernet0/1" | "Gi0/48"                 | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | 199345                 |
| 30836    | "dummy1.rrfaae.com" | "eth1"        | "eth1"                   | "dummy2.rrfaae.com" | 199345                 |
| 30837    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/1"       | "eth0"                   | "web01.rrfaae.com"  | 199345                 |
| 30838    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/2"       | "eth1"                   | "web01.rrfaae.com"  | 199345                 |
| 30840    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/4"       | "eth1"                   | "web02.rrfaae.com"  | 199345                 |
| 30841    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/3"       | "eth0"                   | "web02.rrfaae.com"  | 199345                 |
| 30842    | "db01.rrfaae.com"   | "serial"      | "serial"                 | "db02.rrfaae.com"   | 199345                 |
| 30843    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/5"       | "eth0"                   | "db01.rrfaae.com"   | 199345                 |
| 30844    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/6"       | "eth1"                   | "db01.rrfaae.com"   | 199345                 |
| 30845    | "db01.rrfaae.com"   | "eth2"        | "eth2"                   | "db02.rrfaae.com"   | 199345                 |
| 30846    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/7"       | "eth0"                   | "db02.rrfaae.com"   | 199345                 |
| 30847    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/8"       | "eth1"                   | "db02.rrfaae.com"   | 199345                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In this case, `b3s5r12k11s1.liquidweb.com` has a lower ID than of the devices connected to it, but won't show up in subA due to it having it's acct property as 22.

It seems the `DISTINCT` qualifier in the `RETURN` statement works, but only if the only column is `id(conn)`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Jason

Comment: Is the problem that `subA` binds some, but not all, nodes that are also bound as `subB`, because some but not all `subB` have `acct=199345`, and `id(subA)<id(subB)` would work only if this was the case for all `subB`? Would it work to replace the id ordering filter with `WHERE subB.acct <> 199345`?

Comment: The problem is duplicate tuples are being returned (albeit the tuples are in a different order). It's perfectly ok, though, for subB.acct to be 199345

Comment: I think if you include results where `subB.acct=199345` you'll get duplicates since your pattern is symmetric (the same path will be matched in both directions--duplicate tuples in different order). The cases where a `:Subaccount` has `acct=199345` is already covered under `subA`, you'll get all the valid paths.

Comment: Actually, @ulkas updated query gave me some ideas, and it seems to have worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe when using the condition `id(subA) < id(subB)`, you must ommit the relationship direction:

```
MATCH (subA:`Subaccount` {acct: 199345})-[:`contains`]-(intA:`Physical Interface`)-[conn:`connects`]-(intB:`Physical Interface`)-[:`contains`]-(subB:`Subaccount`)
WHERE id(subA) < id(subB)
RETURN DISTINCT id(conn), subA.name, intA.name, intB.name AS `Connected Host Interface`, subB.name AS `Connected Host`, subB.acct AS `Connected Host Account`
ORDER BY id(conn);
```

**edit:**

than you can use quite a longer statement with `WITH`:

```
MATCH (subA:`Subaccount` {acct: 199345})-[:`contains`]->(intA:`Physical Interface`)-[conn:`connects`]-(intB:`Physical Interface`)<-[:`contains`]-(subB:`Subaccount`)
WITH conn
MATCH (subA:`Subaccount`)-[:`contains`]->(intA:`Physical Interface`)-[conn:`connects`]-(intB:`Physical Interface`)<-[:`contains`]-(subB:`Subaccount`)
WHERE id(subA) < id(subB)
RETURN DISTINCT id(conn), subA.name, intA.name, intB.name AS `Connected Host Interface`, subB.name AS `Connected Host`, subB.acct AS `Connected Host Account`
ORDER BY id(conn);
```

Comment: that wouldn't work (and I did test to verify) as in this case even though the node identified by `b3s5r12k11s1.liquidweb.com`has a lower ID than `fw.rrfaae.com`, `dummy2.rrfaae.com`, and `dummy1.rrfaae.com`, it won't show as a match for subA as a result of it not having it's `acct` property being 199345

Comment: The longer statement does indeed seem to do the trick. It seems there would be a more elegant way of doing things though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still want @ulkas to get credit, as his updated query gave me the idea to try this:

**Edit:**

```
MATCH (subA:`Subaccount`)-[:`contains`]->(intA:`Physical Interface`)-[conn:`connects`]-(intB:`Physical Interface`)<-[:`contains`]-(subB:`Subaccount`)
WHERE (subA.acct = 199345 AND id(subA) < id(subB)) OR (subA.acct = 199345 AND subB.acct <> 199345)
RETURN subA.name, intA.name, intB.name, subB.name
ORDER BY subA.name;
```

Result set:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id(conn) | subA.name           | intA.name     | Connected Host Interface | Connected Host               | Connected Host Account |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 30832    | "fw.rrfaae.com"     | "ethernet0/0" | "Gi0/1"                  | "b3s5r12k11s1.liquidweb.com" | 22                     |
| 30833    | "fw.rrfaae.com"     | "ethernet0/1" | "Gi0/48"                 | "sw.rrfaae.com"              | 199345                 |
| 30834    | "dummy2.rrfaae.com" | "eth0"        | "Gi0/2"                  | "b3s5r12k11s1.liquidweb.com" | 22                     |
| 30835    | "dummy1.rrfaae.com" | "eth0"        | "Gi0/3"                  | "b3s5r12k11s1.liquidweb.com" | 22                     |
| 30836    | "dummy1.rrfaae.com" | "eth1"        | "eth1"                   | "dummy2.rrfaae.com"          | 199345                 |
| 30837    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/1"       | "eth0"                   | "web01.rrfaae.com"           | 199345                 |
| 30838    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/2"       | "eth1"                   | "web01.rrfaae.com"           | 199345                 |
| 30840    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/4"       | "eth1"                   | "web02.rrfaae.com"           | 199345                 |
| 30841    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/3"       | "eth0"                   | "web02.rrfaae.com"           | 199345                 |
| 30842    | "db01.rrfaae.com"   | "serial"      | "serial"                 | "db02.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30843    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/5"       | "eth0"                   | "db01.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30844    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/6"       | "eth1"                   | "db01.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30845    | "db01.rrfaae.com"   | "eth2"        | "eth2"                   | "db02.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30846    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/7"       | "eth0"                   | "db02.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
| 30847    | "sw.rrfaae.com"     | "Gi0/8"       | "eth1"                   | "db02.rrfaae.com"            | 199345                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```